# How to decide which feature in model can be deleted (feature selection)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, linear-regression, feature-selection

I'm new to Machine Learning, and I'm working on dataset "`Combined Cycle Power Plant over 6 years (2006-2011)`", when the power plant was set to work with full load. Features consist of hourly average ambient variables Temperature (AT), Ambient Pressure (AP), Relative Humidity (RH) and Exhaust Vacuum (V) to predict the net hourly electrical energy output (PE) of the plant.

And this is my output:
[image]

How I can decide to remove 1 feature that may not be as important as the other ones for prediction. (since the data has been normalized, may be done by looking at the weights of each feature in the learned model.)
The Linear Regression coefficients (weight) of columns (features - `'AT', 'V', 'AP', 'RH', 'PE'`) which I calculated with `numpy.linalg.lstsq` is:

```
[ 4.54458108e+02 -1.44125679e+01 -3.11527582e+00  3.78157228e-01 -2.06364959e+00]
```

In this case, I guess I can choose the third one which is 'AP' to remove from features. Is that correct?

Comment: Why not `RH`? It has the smallest weighting.

Comment: Could you please describe that more? I tought -3.11 which is for 'AP' is smallest and less important feature.

Comment: The closer the absolute value is to `0` the less it is correlated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about deleting features and not losing performance, I suggest you check the correlation between your data points.

You could use the correlation pandas already has built in.

```
corr_matrix = df.corr()
corr_matrix[['AT', 'AP', 'RH', 'V']]
```

And see the output. For any two features X and Y, if they are tightly correlated, then it is not wise to use both of them. You can easily remove any one. Alternatively, you can combine the two features and label them as Z = XY and use them as one feature.

The correlation matrix is as follows

[image]

```
# using all the attributes
X = df.drop(['PE', 'RH'], axis=1)
y = df['PE']

lr = LinearRegression()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=27)
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
lr.predict(X_test)
print(lr.score(X_test, y_test))
```

```
>>> 0.9297044622422397
```

Now removing RH (since it has the least correlation)

```
X = df.drop(['PE', 'RH'], axis=1)
y = df['PE']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=27)
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
lr.predict(X_test)
print(lr.score(X_test, y_test))
```

```
>>> 0.9175575321043363
```

I suggest you remove RH and see how the model performs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For the output of the above commands, I looked at the 'PE' row, so the values for  `AT, AP, RH, V` are: `-0.948063, 0.515911, 0.398256, -0.871499` . Could you please help with this output? the RH can be remove because of less correlation? (But we have 2 negative values too, I don't know what that means).

Comment: @danial could you tell me what are you looking for? I guess you want to reduce the number of features. Have you done any data preprocessing apart from normalization? The ```numpy.linalg.lstsq``` gives the least square error which only tells the error of the residuals.

Comment: Yes. I want to remove a less important feature. For data preprocessing I did this for training, validation, and test sets.
`scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_training)`
and `X_training = scaler.transform(X_training)`

Comment: @danial combine both of them and use the ```fit_transform``` method. However, I used the model without using ```StandardScaler``` and the accuracies were the same.

Comment: @danial the correlation values for AT, V, AP and RH with respect to the class EP is [-0.948, -0.869, 0.518, 0.389]. A value close to -1 indicates a negative correlation (when one variable increases, other decreases), +1 for a positive correlation (when one increases, other one also increases). A value close to 0 shows no correlation.

Comment: Thanks for the provided information. I get my answer.